Is there a less bloated alternative to GDAL and GeoDjango?
I am writing an API in Django and need to filter posts by a search radius and later on will need live tracking like on Uber. I am wondering if there is an easier way to query for posts and filter them based on a search radius defined by the user and their location. Wondering how a program like AutoTrader would do this.
Dealing with the installation process for GDAL is a complete pain for Windows and my docker image. I know there are ways to install a pre-built wheel and blah blah blah but I'm looking for a streamlined approach that is as simple as throwing it into my requirements and won't be a nuisance after each release.

How accurate does the search by radius need to be? You can probably use the Haversine formula in a Django ORM query.

You may just use GDAL via the database (so a gis query), or I would improve the way you use to build the image. Maybe miniconda, maybe linux docker images which already include gdal, maybe cython or pyinstaller (and just copying the support libraries in the right place, which they tell you where, not using the final exe). Try to solve the main problem, I'm not sure workaround will be easier
